# Return Text Value from Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel

i have a workbook with multiple worksheets (about 30). each sheet has a different, complicated name.

i want to return the value of cell B6 from every alternate sheet (each one has a suffix of "-a") into a summary sheet.

how do i go about doing this?

thanks in advance.

g

Comment: We don't write code for people we help. What have you tried? See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vba code **not tested:**

```
Sub test()
A = 1
For each s in activeworkbook.sheets
    If right(s.name, 2) = "-a" then
        With Sheets("summary")
            .cells(a, "a") = s.name
            .cells(a, "b") = s.range("b6")
        End with
    End if
Next
End sub
```

To run right click on sheet tab, view code, paste the code in and run from the menu.

To run for all remove the `if` statement.

Comment: thx for your help. not sure how to use this script. also if i want every sheet rather than alternate how does the script change?